Image assets on https domain 500 response (VITE, Netlify)
After deployed my qwik app with netlify on a https domain, every image breaks with 500.
At first i thought the issue was that the images request was http://,
I hcanged everything and the netlify function error is https://example.com/assets/aboutus/home6.png): error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: NotValidForName.
Trying to access the image in the browser (https) gives following
error :

This edge function has crashed

An unhandled error in the function code triggered the following message:

uncaught exception during edge function invocation

I tryed redirecting from http to https.
Different vite configurations as base etc...
